# How can I attached a background image from url in this html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

here the html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Frozen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron|Montserrat">
    </head>
    <body onload="showtime();">
        <div> 
        <h1>BATMAN</h1>
        <h2>
            
        <span id="h"></span>
        <span id="blink">:</span>
        <span id="m"></span>
        <span id="blink">:</span>
        <span id="s"></span>
        
        </h2>
            
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the css part:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:black;
}
h1{
    text-align:center ;
    color:black;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    text-shadow:  0 0 2px lime
               ,  0 0 4px lime
               ,  0 0 6px lime
               ,  0 0 8px lime;
               
}
div{
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:black;
    border:1px solid lime;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin:auto ;
    margin-top:20%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px lime;
}
h2{
     color:black;
     font-family: Orbitron;
     font-size:33px;
     font-weight:bold ;
     text-align:center ;
     margin-top:20px;
}
#h,#m,#s{
      text-shadow:  0 0 2px lime
                 ,  0 0 4px lime
                 ,  0 0 6px lime
                 ,  0 0 8px lime;
}
#blink{
    text-shadow:  0 0 2px lime
               ,  0 0 4px lime
               ,  0 0 6px lime
               ,  0 0 8px lime;
    animation:animate 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        color:lime;
        text-shadow:  0 0 2px lime
                   ,  0 0 4px lime
                   ,  0 0 6px lime
                   ,  0 0 8px lime;
    }
    100%
    {
        color:black;
        text-shadow:  0 0 2px black
                   ,  0 0 4px black
                   ,  0 0 6px black
                   ,  0 0 8px black;
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript file:

```
function showtime()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("h");
    var b = document.getElementById("m");
    var c = document.getElementById("s");
    var i = document.getElementById("d");
    var time = new Date();
    var h = time.getHours();
    var m = time.getMinutes();
    var s = time.getSeconds();
    if(h<=9)
    {
        h= "0"+h;
    }
    if(m<=9)
    {
        m= "0"+m;
    }
    if(s<=9)
    {
        s="0"+s;
    }
    a.innerHTML = h;
    b.innerHTML = m;
    c.innerHTML = s;
    
}

setInterval(showtime ,1000);
```

Basically I is a digital clock name BATMAN. I wanna attached an background image url (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ddfIP5iy9RAgG9lF5xGYgYGHKW_glrsy/view?usp=sharing) there. I change the body elements of my style script below:

```
<style>
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image: url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ddfIP5iy9RAgG9lF5xGYgYGHKW_glrsy/view?usp=sharing');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
</style>
```

But it neither shown in my html page as a background. I download the picture and upload it into my drive. I want to know my mistakes? I am at the beginner stage of CSS/CSS3 and javascript. I am better at HTML5/HTML. I realize the javascript file but some problems in css file. I am sure that if any professional programmer/developer suggests to me about my mistakes, I will get the point. HELP...

Comment: You cannot link an image directly from a secured drive. You need to upload the image on a webserver.

Comment: @Archer Is that only a mistake or anything else?  If I upload the image to a server then the link will be ok, right?

Comment: The image is not just an image. It's embedded into the google drive preview, so it's mime type is `text/html` and not an image. For testing purposes, just tag the url from another image of the net.

Comment: It is clear to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be your Background image path is not working, try this and it will work

```
body { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("https://kivabe.com/code/media/img/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```

so, if you are developing your project in your local machine, make sure you are suing right path of your Background image.

Assuming that your project file/folder structure like below

```
 /project/ 
    |---index.html
    ├── css/
    │   └── style.css 
    ├── js/
    │   └──functions.js  
    └── images/
        └── image.png
```

then you have to use background image path as

```
background-image: url("../image.png");
```